# Is displaying an HTML email a security risk?

Tags: security, email

I am writing a simple webmail where I want (obviously) to display the emails.

I'm wondering if I should take any precaution while displaying HTML emails: is dumping the email content into a `<div>` a security risk?

I'm guessing that yes since the email could contain anything (could it contain Javascript?). But then how should I proceed? How do other webmails do?

I'm thinking that stripping dangerous HTML tags would be a bad solution since it's impossible to think of all the cases.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the security risks.  Why build this yourself?  There are a number of open source webmail solutions available.

Comment: @dan1111 Thanks for your comment, but I definitely don't want to go down that path of discussing whether or not I want to do what I want to do :) (I have a bit of experience of stack exchange to know it leads nowhere)

Comment: Of course, it leads nowhere if you ask a question and arbitrarily ignore *any* advice ;-).  This is such a complex problem that you *really* should pick something off the shelf.  Unless, of course there is a "thou shalt not" style blockage (e.g. it's for coursework) in which case stating the fact will help avoid such comment trails.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli, fair enough. But think of it from the opposite perspective: why should people spend time helping solve a problem that has a solution freely available?  *A lot* of questions on SO arise from attempts to reinvent the wheel.  If you want to head off this kind of criticism, having your question say why you want to do this would help.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is insecure and problematic in many ways:

- JavaScript inside the mail could hijack the session (XSS) or do other things
- CSS in the mail could break your layout
- Images and other resources loaded from remote sites can e used for tracking and thus have privacy issues
- Links in mails might carry private info in the referrer

Filtering against these things is actually the key trouble for a web mailer. Filtering is not easy as you not only have to filter out `<script>` tags but also a bunch of attributes (like javascript event handlers)

A plain whitelist will break too many mails, though.

What you need is to collect a huge amount of sample mails from different sources and see what elements they actually need and provide these.

Comment: Not to mention that links in e-mails may be phishing links.  Depends entirely on how "safe" OP would like to be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm surprised it's such a problem, there are so **many** mail clients how do they *all* do if that is so complex? And I mean "Safe" like any other webmail (i.e. not necessarily the safest in the world). Phishing/beacons are out of scope (for my question at least), I'm not focusing on privacy or human error-related risks (yet).

Comment: Some limit to plain text or very limited HTML, many are broken :-/

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Many of them are not so safe. The ones that are (relatively speaking), have spent _significant_ effort to become so.

Comment: @johannes I don't know what mail clients you have experience with, but very few support the majority of CSS features and fewer still execute Javascript.

Comment: @GlennNelson hopefully no mail client executes javascript, but the question was about "dumping the email content into a `<div>`". Simply dumping the HTL mail in a `<div>` in a web mailer will execute javascript which is embedded in a mail.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you are asking the end user to place the same trust they  give your web domain to the content of the HTML email, the content of which, you have limited control over.

The only safe way that I know for sure is reliable is to strip the HTML email down to pure and simple text and text formatting options such as p, em tags.   Although this is hardly what people would consider HTML email.

Start allowing anything beyond presentational tags and you are making assumptions that you know more about how these tags can be misused than the mal-ware writers.  And believe me, that is a brave claim for anyone to make.